# Querying data from two SQL servers without using Linked Server or OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server

I need to extract data from two databases which are on two different servers. But I can't use Linked server or OPENQUERY. Is there any other way to extract the data?

Comment: Looks like your stuffed. I did some research on this previously and without a linked server this is not possible.

Comment: Whats wrong with `linked server` ?

Comment: If you absolutely can't use the listed tools, worst case, you can right click on the database, select **Tasks** and then select **Export Data...** which you would then **BULK INSERT** or import through the GUI or some other tool, like SSIS.  Note that this is the longest route and if you can use other tools, by all means, use them (for instance, you can remote into a server with PowerShell using **enter-pssession MYSERVER** and from there connecting to the instance).

Comment: I only have a readonly access to the database... Thats why I cant use any of these procedures... I will explain my situation more clearly.... when I was migrating an application from one server to another there was a column in the SQL which failed to restore resulting in blank value. I cant do restore again as the new server is being used more than a month resulting in more amount of new data. I need to insert the column values from the old server to the new server for the ond transactions..

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use a Linked Server or Open Query, then you will have to migrate the data between environments. Those are the only ways to do cross-server queries.

There are multiple different ETL tools available that can move the information between environments, such as SSIS or Informatica.

It's worth noting that even with Linked Server connections that you can encounter performance issues and transactions which are held open from one end of the connection resulting in blocking transactions even when selecting very small amounts of information through the linked connection.

Comment: The main Problem is that I don't have permissions to create Linked server and using other tools.. I only have a readonly access to the database... Thats why I cant use any of these procedures...